# ListView loses formatting when scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have made one Adapter to my ListView and I want to programmatically change the color of some lines if they have the value I specified.

The code below shows how this is implemented. Two strange things happen:

1) The first line should be painted, but was not being;

2) The others lines (except first) are being colorful, but when you execute a scroll it loses the background color.

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
        convertView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate( resource, null );
        Content Legend = getItem( position );

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(Legend.getName());

        TextView value = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.value);

        if (Legend.getValue().equals("Color")){
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Legend.setValue("");
        }*/
        value.setText(Legend.getValue());

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the view in listView will be reused, try to think you are set each view in one place. So you need consider every situation, add **else{}**

```
if (Legend.getValue().equals("Color")){
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        Legend.setValue("");
    } else {
  //set background and other value if not equals "color"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
static class ViewHolderItem {
    TextView name, value;
public ViewHolderItem(View view) {
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
 value = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.value);
}


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolderItem holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxx, parent, false);
            holder = new MyHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (MyHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
            Content Legend = getItem( position );
            holder.name.setText(Legend.getName());

 if (Legend.getValue().equals("Color")){
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            holder.value.setText("whatever you wanna show or keep it empty");
          //whatever you wanna do
        }
else{
holder.value.setText(Legend.getValue());
}
```